# Acumatica Purchase Order Receipt API Can not find PO Order Nbr

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create a Purchase Receipt with a detail line item that is on a Purchase Order.  When I do this with the API, I get an error back saying that the PO could not be found in the system.  I can add line items fine if I do not reference the PO, but as soon as I reference the PO the API errors.  The PO number is valid and the item is on the PO.

I can do this manually in Acumatica with no problem and the PO is in fact available and like a said doing it manually has no problems.

Here is the simple JSON request I am making.

```
{
    "CreateBill": {"value": true},
    "VendorID": {"value": "ARTISTICCARP"},
    "Details": [
        {
            "InventoryID": {"value":"VND1807 4x6"},
            "ReceiptQty": {"value": 1},
            "POOrderNbr": {"value": "001131" },
            "POLineNbr": {"value": 1},
            "POOrderType": {"value": "Goods for IN"}
           
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
 "innerException": {
            "message": "An error has occurred.",
            "exceptionMessage": "OrderNbr=Order Nbr. '001131' cannot be found in the system.",
            "exceptionType": "PX.Data.PXException",
            "stackTrace": "   at PX.Objects.DefaultEndpointImpl.PurchaseReceiptDetail_Insert(PXGraph graph, EntityImpl entity, EntityImpl targetEntity)"
        }
```

Comment: Can you list POs under the vendor?

Comment: Yes I can list them.  and I can do attach it manually (not through the api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
{
"CreateBill": {"value": true},
"VendorRef": {"value": "FROM_API"},
"VendorID": {"value": "ARTISTICCARP"},
"Details": [
    {
        "InventoryID": {"value":"VND1807 4x6"},
        "ReceiptQty": {"value": 1},
        "POOrderNbr": {"value": "001131" },
        "POLineNbr": {"value": 1},
        "POOrderType": {"value": "Normal"}
       
    }]
}
```

You passed in a wrong order type that's why it cannot find the purchase order. And you also need a Vendor Ref if CreateBill = true.

Comment: That was it! Copy and paste issue and I looked at this 20 times!. Although I did not need the VendorRef, but I am adding one.  Thanks for the response.  I wish this API did not require the POLineNbr, it makes what we are trying to do here very complicated.