# Acumatica Create PO Receipt via API setting the detail line po data does not create the PO Receipt Orders Link

Tags: acumatica

I am creating a PO receipt via my own custom endpoint using the rest API.  I can create the receipt and add the lines ok and even assign a PO Nbr, Line Nbr etc to the line as well.  But when I view the PO Receipt in Acumatica the the PO Receipt Order Link does not appear under the Purchase Orders tab.

Is there something I have to do to get this link there?  As I think it affects tax amounts when the bill is created.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Acumatica version are you working with?

I created a PO Receipt via Postman using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251817/acumatica-purchase-order-receipt-api-can-not-find-po-order-nbr) reference.

I adapted it to my data (Acumatica Sales Demo data) as follows:
[image]

The result looks correct in Acumatica:

- We have the Purchase Receipt with the correct reference to the source PO:
  [image]
- We have the reference to the Purchase Receipt in the PO page:
  [image]

Comment: I am using 18.200 API version as well

Comment: Using the Default endpoint it works, but using my own custom endpoint doesnt

Comment: try to create a new extended endpoint from scratch using Default as the reference. if it does not work, export it as a customization package and send it here

Comment: Yea that's I did and it works.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer and not sure if this is a bug in Acumatica.

But if make the call

```
{
"CreateBill": {"value": true},
"VendorID": {"value": "500508"},
"VendorRef": {"value": "VendorREF"},
"Details": [
    {
        "InventoryID": {"value":"E/104038"},
        "ReceiptQty": {"value": 1},
        "POOrderNbr": {"value": "40393" },
        "POLineNbr": {"value": 1},
        "POOrderType": {"value": "Normal"}
       
    }
]
```

}

On the Default API endpoint, the receipt appears on the PO.

If I make the same call on my own custom endpoint it doesnt